# OCaml sharing constraints

Tags: ocaml

I'm reading about sharing constraints in [Real World Ocaml](https://v1.realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/functors.html#sharing-constraints), and can't get the part about exposing `endpoint` to work by changing the module type signature.

```ml
open Core

module type Interval_intf = sig
  type t
  type endpoint
  val create : endpoint -> endpoint -> t
  val is_empty : t -> bool
  val contains : t -> endpoint -> bool
  val intersect : t -> t -> t
end

module Make_interval(Endpoint: Comparable): Interval_intf = struct
  type endpoint = Endpoint.t

  type t =
    | Interval of Endpoint.t * Endpoint.t
    | Empty

  let create low high =
    if Endpoint.compare low high > 0 then Empty
    else Interval (low, high)

  let is_empty = function
    | Empty -> true
    | Interval _ -> false

  let contains t x =
    match t with
    | Empty -> false
    | Interval (l, h) -> Endpoint.compare x l >= 0 && Endpoint.compare x h <= 0

  let intersect t1 t2 =
    let min x y = if Endpoint.compare x y <= 0 then x else y in
    let max x y = if Endpoint.compare x y >= 0 then x else y in
    match t1, t2 with
    | Empty, _ | _, Empty -> Empty
    | Interval (l1, h1), Interval (l2, h2) -> create (max l1 l2) (min h1 h2)
end

module Int_interval_intf : (Interval_intf with type endpoint = int) = Make_interval(Int)
```

This gives an error:

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
       ...
       Type declarations do not match:
         type endpoint = Make_interval(Core_kernel__Int).endpoint
       is not included in
         type endpoint = int
```

What's the problem here?

This is w/ OCaml 4.06.0 and Core v0.11.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module type constraint on the result type of `Make_interval` is too opaque. Indeed, the constraint is making the type `endpoint` abstract. And since they are no functions that produce an `endpoint` in the `Interval_intf` signature *without* requiring an `endpoint` as input, this makes the resulting module useless.

```
module Make_interval(Endpoint: Comparable): Interval_intf with type endpoint = ...
```